# I'm having trouble getting CardLayout change cards in my simple program

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager, cardlayout

This constructor exists to make a frame with four panels inside. Each of these panels are supposed to be able to cycle between an empty panel and panel with content on it using a card layout. (the first panel starts with the content being displayed, but card layout is needed for future use) I have only finished adding the elements for the first and third panel but the cards are already giving me issues. I have tried many things but nothing seems to help my case.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Menu implements ActionListener{

    //Create an array of names for the panels
    String[] panelNames = {"part1", "part2", "part3", "part4"};

    //Create an array of panels
    JPanel[] panels = new JPanel[panelNames.length];

    //creates an array of the cards to be added to the panels created above
    JPanel[] cards = new JPanel[panelNames.length];

    //Create an array of buttons
    JButton[] buttons1 = new JButton[4];

    //Create an array of buttons
    JButton[] buttons2 = new JButton[4];

    //create a default panel for the initially empty panels
    JPanel empty = new JPanel();

    //Create a layout
    CardLayout c = new CardLayout();

    Menu(){

        //Create a JFrame to hold the panels
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
        frame.setTitle("Select your application"); 
        frame.setSize(700,700);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Panel that contains the four panels needed for this assignment
        JPanel parts = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));

        //a loop that creates each panels and fills it with the cards
        for(int i = 0 ; i < panelNames.length ; i++){

            //define the panels and adds them to the frame
            panels[i] = new JPanel(c);
            panels[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
            cards[i] = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            parts.add(panels[i]);
            panels[i].add(empty, "empty");
            panels[i].add(cards[i], "card");
            c.show(panels[i], "empty");
        }
        c.show(panels[0], "card");
        frame.add(parts, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //adds 4 buttons to the first panel and names them
        Border line = new LineBorder(Color.GRAY,1);
        cards[0].setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
        for(int i = 0 ; i < buttons1.length ; i++){

            buttons1[i] = new JButton("TBA");
            buttons1[i].setBackground(Color.white);
            buttons1[i].setBorder(line);
            buttons1[i].addActionListener(this);
            cards[0].add(buttons1[i]);
        }
        buttons1[0].setText("Sudoku");

        //adds 4 buttons to the 3rd panel and names them
        cards[2].setLayout(new GridLayout(4,1));
        for(int i = 0 ; i < buttons2.length ; i++){

            buttons2[i] = new JButton();
            buttons2[i].setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            buttons2[i].addActionListener(this);
            cards[2].add(buttons2[i]);
            buttons2[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
        buttons2[0].setText("Sample");
        buttons2[1].setText("Solution");
        buttons2[2].setText("Verify");
        buttons2[3].setText("Return to main");

        //adds the exit button and the exit panels to the frame
        JPanel exit = new JPanel();
        frame.add(exit, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        JButton exitb = new JButton("exit");
        exitb.setBackground(Color.red);
        exitb.setForeground(Color.white);
        exitb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(245,30));
        exit.add(exitb);
        exitb.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 

                System.exit(0);
            } 
        });

        //show the frame
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    //method that determined which app to launch and launches it
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        //finds the source of the event
        Object src = ae.getSource();

        //these statements do the appropriate actions when a button is pressed
        if(src == buttons1[0]){

            c.show(panels[2], "card");
            buttons2[0].setEnabled(true);
            buttons2[3].setEnabled(true);

        }

        else if(src == buttons2[0]){

            buttons2[1].setEnabled(true);
            buttons2[0].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if(src == buttons2[1]){

            buttons2[2].setEnabled(true);
            buttons2[1].setEnabled(false);
        }
        else if(src == buttons2[2]){

            buttons2[2].setEnabled(false);    
        }
        else if(src == buttons2[3]){

            c.show(panels[2], "empty");
            for(int i = 0 ; i < buttons1.length ; i++){buttons2[i].setEnabled(false);
                                                       buttons1[i].setEnabled(true);}
        }

        else{System.out.println("option not yet implemented");}
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please clarify: What behaviors are you expecting vs what behaviors are you experiencing?

Comment: I "think" you mis understand how `CardLayout` works, you're suppose to add the "cards" to the container which is using `CardLayout`, not set `CardLayout` to the "cards"...

Comment: A component can only have one parent, each time you add a component to another container, it is first removed from it's current container...

Comment: I'm expecting all the panels to start out with empty cards (with the exception of the first one) and then change to another panel when a certain button is pressed.

Comment: If this were my project, I'd refactor things and create a class for your panels, and thereby try to greatly reduce redundancy and bugs. Class size is partially determined by testability.

Comment: MadProgrammer, does that mean that I should make 4 different empty panels?

Comment: Your containers cannot share components, that's for sure. But again, if you had a base class for your Panel, it would have its own empty panel.

Comment: @user3053361 Yes! Doing that, I actually end up with an empty screen...

Comment: I'm also no sure you can share `CardLayout` across multiple containers...

Comment: yes, I also tried it and I got the empty screen

Comment: No, now I'm certain you can't.  `CardLayout` has a single `Vector` which contains a list of `Card`, which uses the `name` as part of it's internal logic, the name is, in no way, associated with the parent container...

Comment: I tried making a card layout for each of the panels and it's now working!

Thanks a lot guys, I got to learn something today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A component can only reside within a single container.  Each time you add the component to another container, it is first (effectively) removed from it's current parent.  You can't re-use `empty` the way you are.
- `CardLayout` can not manage multiple containers, it is responsible for the management of a single container.

My "gut" feeling would be to create a separate custom class extending from `JPanel` which had a `show` method which would allow you to show the named component.  This panel would use it's own `CardLayout` and manage its internal state.  This would allow you a jumping of point for adding additional content as required...